# VBA code to open different versions of excel files, as some users are using office 2000 and some are using office 2013

Tags: vba

Here is my VBA code.
It currently opens all excel documents in a file that are xlsx and the name of each document ends with "Daily" in the name. I have unfortunately just found that several users of these documents will be accessing them through a much older version of excel "2000" and my VBA will not work with their versions? 
Can someone help me? Changing xlsx to xls just crashes my system.**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub processFiles()

Dim strProductivityFiles As String, strProductivityArchive As String,       
strProductivityResult As String

Let Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Let strProductivityFiles = "\*Daily.xlsx*"
Let strProductivityArchive = "\Archive\"
Let strProductivityResult = "\daily_productivity.txt"

AgentProductivity strProductivityFiles, strProductivityArchive,
strProductivityResult

Let Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub

Private Sub AgentProductivity(strImportFile As String, strArchivePath As    
String, strResultFile As String)

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wbkData As Workbook
Dim wksData As Worksheet
Dim namData As Name
Dim ranData As Range
Dim ranCell As Range
Dim strAgent As String
Dim strQueue As String
Dim datDate As Date
Dim dblVolume As Double
Dim dblTime As Double
Dim lngArrayRow As Long
Dim varOutput() As Variant
ReDim varOutput(200000, 12)

Set wbk = Application.ActiveWorkbook

If (Dir(wbk.Path & strResultFile) <> "") Then
Kill wbk.Path & strResultFile
End If

Let strImportFile = Dir(wbk.Path & strImportFile)
Let lngArrayRow = 0

Do While strImportFile <> ""
If Right(strImportFile, 4) = "xlsx*" Then

    Set wbkData = Workbooks.Open(wbk.Path & "\" & strImportFile)
    'Let lngArrayRow = 0
    'ReDim Preserve varOutput(20000, 5)

    For Each namData In wbkData.Names
        If (namData.Name = "Data") Then
            Set ranData = Range(namData)
        End If
        If (namData.Name = "User") Then
            Let strAgent = Range(namData).Value
        End If
    Next namData

    For Each ranCell In ranData
        If (ranCell.Row >= 3) And (ranCell.Column >= 3) And ((ranCell.Row  
    Mod 2) > 0) Then
            Let strQueue = Cells(ranCell.Row, 1)
            Let datDate = Cells(2, ranCell.Column)
            Let dblVolume = Cells(ranCell.Row + 1, ranCell.Column)
            Let dblTime = Cells(ranCell.Row, ranCell.Column)
            If (dblVolume > 0) Or (dblTime > 0) Then
                Let varOutput(lngArrayRow, 0) = strAgent
                Let varOutput(lngArrayRow, 1) = strQueue
                Let varOutput(lngArrayRow, 2) = datDate
                Let varOutput(lngArrayRow, 3) = dblVolume
                Let varOutput(lngArrayRow, 4) = dblTime
                Let lngArrayRow = lngArrayRow + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next ranCell

    wbkData.SaveAs wbk.Path & strArchivePath & wbkData.Name,   
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wbkData.Close

    Let strImportFile = Dir()

    End If
    Loop

ExportData5Fields wbk.Path & strResultFile, varOutput

End Sub

Private Sub ExportData5Fields(strFile As String, varArray() As Variant)

Dim lngFile As Long
Let lngFile = FreeFile()
Dim lngCounter As Long

If (Dir(strFile) <> "") Then
Open strFile For Append As #lngFile
Else
Open strFile For Append As #lngFile
Print #lngFile, """" & "CitrixID" & """," & _
                """" & "Workstream" & """," & _
                """" & "Date" & """," & _
                """" & "Volume" & """," & _
                """" & "Minutes" & """"
End If

For lngCounter = 0 To UBound(varArray, 1)
If Not IsEmpty(varArray(lngCounter, 0)) Then
    Print #lngFile, """" & varArray(lngCounter, 0) & """," & _
                    """" & varArray(lngCounter, 1) & """," & _
                    """" & varArray(lngCounter, 2) & """," & _
                    """" & varArray(lngCounter, 3) & """," & _
                    """" & varArray(lngCounter, 4) & """"
End If
Next lngCounter

enter code here

Close #lngFile

End Sub
```

Comment: "Changing xlsx to xls just crashes my system." So if you run your code with the ".xls" files, your Excel crashes? What's the error? Can you open the ".xls" files manually?

Answer (score 0):

The VBA would work however Excel 2000 cannot by default open .xlsx files.

Either have whatever is generating the files in the first place switch to generating .xls format files or install the [Office 2007 Compatibility Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3) on machines running Office 2000 to enable them to work with the newer format files.

Comment: I will attempt to upgrade all users to 2007 but this will cost up to £1000. Is there any possible way I could incorporate something into my VBA to open  all the .xls versions and save them as xlsx? Then my VBA can continue with it's process and export all the data as text for me then to use?

Comment: Install the compatibility pack and Excel 2000 should be able to open .xlsx